# How do I validate a form field is empty

Tags: forms, validation, hidden-field

I have created a simple html form. Within it is a hidden field that is empty.

I wish to create a javascript warning if the field becomes populated and stops the form from being submitted.

This in my view would prevent bots from submitting the form as they will automatically populate the field. It doesn't matter what I put into searches, they always assume I wish to check if the field is empty, not populated.

I have tried editing the 'opposite' script to do this but to no avail.

Can anybody help.

Comment: To add to above. It appears I need the opposite to validateForm() which checks if a field is empty. I want it to check if the field is NOT empty which will prevent the form from being submitted. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: The title of this questions should be:
How do I validate a form field is NOT empty.